# Continue On Error Smartsheet SDK on python

Tags: python, json, smartsheet-api

I'm Trying to list the users of my domain smartsheet to backup their data one by one.
For that i need to list them then for every id i retrieve user Home with ss.Home.list_all_content()
the first one is ok, but the second give me this error when i try to retrieve his home or just make a ss.Users.get_User(his id) see below error:

```json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#84>", line 1, in <module>
    ss.Users.list_users(include_all=True)
  File "D:\Users\maxime.champain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\users.py", line 277, in list_users
    response = self._base.request(prepped_request, expected, _op)
  File "D:\Users\maxime.champain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\smartsheet.py", line 218, in request
    raise the_ex(native, str(native.result.code) + ': ' + native.result.message)
smartsheet.exceptions.ApiError: {"result": {"shouldRetry": false, "refId": null, "code": 5349, "recommendation": "Do not retry without fixing the problem. ", "statusCode": 400, "message": "You must agree to the Smartsheet User Agreement before using Smartsheet.  These terms can be viewed the next time you log in to https://app.smartsheet.com from a desktop browser.", "name": "ApiError"}, "requestResponse": null}
```

## Question

How can I simply bypass this error to continue the program.

The exception of this error is handled by the smartsheet api sdk but i don't know how to call it.

regards,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch this exception and continue, you'll need to use the `try` and `except` keywords.
There are many tutorials on the web, here's one: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: I already search for that but I don't know wich expect is it or even where to place it to bypass the error

The test of the error should be like that :  
ss.Users.get_user(id)  
And then with that the catch error would be like that ?

try:  
  ss.Users.get_user(id)  
except:  
  pass